# How do web development companies host websites under development for client review

Tags: shared-hosting

We are a pretty young website development company. For client review, So far we have been hosting the websites on `clientname.ourcompanydomain.com`. However, these websites start showing up on google in results related to our website which is not a great thing for SEO I guess. otherwise also, not sure if that's a professional approach.

How do other companies do it? Do they have a separate domain for the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to serve the entire client site using the `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` HTTP header. This will instruct search engines to keep it out of results.

Comment: alright. and what's the usual practice followed across industry for this? do people usually create subdomains/ sub directory or something else?

Comment: Using `noindex` is fine, although for anything more high profile, or really anything that you don't want the public to stumble across or tamper with then the development site really needs to be password/IP protected. Subdomains or subdirectories or domains (even the main domain the site will eventually be on) are all OK - it depends on the situation and what resources you have available.